# Suspend/Resume Yields fuzzy screen

Tags: nvidia, suspend, 18.04, nvidia-prime

On `Ubuntu 18.04` with kernel `4.15.0-20-generic`, I get the following screen when resuming from suspension:

[image]

I use default `390` driver for `Nvidia` shipped with Ubuntu:

```
[    1.147280] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.147305] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    1.160605] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.168552] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 241
[    1.175528] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  390.48  Wed Mar 21 23:48:34 PDT 2018
[    1.176853] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    1.176855] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    4.249931] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 240
```

I have the following hardware:

```
~$ lspci 
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
...

~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

After the fuzzy screen appears, I can change volume with keyboard bindings and move the mouse around, but pretty much anything else doesn't work, so I have to reboot the system manually.

The location `/var/crash/` does not contain anything interesting.

I did not have this issue with previous version of Ubuntu `16.04`.

**Q:**

- what is happening?
- how do i fix this?

---

**EDIT:** I tested `Ubuntu 17.10` + `kernel 4.13.0-39-generic` + `nvidia384` + `Gnome 3.26.2` and suspension/resume works without issues.